# Improve IXamlMetadataProvider Performance

Tags: uwp

Under a release build, the UWP toolchain builds a class like you see below. The performance implication of the loop is obvious, especially when you consider that it then loops through `OtherProviders` which (presumably) have their own arrays. The result of the first lookup to `LookupTypeIndexByName` *is* cached in a dictionary, but these loops through the array are a significant portion of application startup under the profiler.

Does anyone have insight on how to customize the build to reduce the execution time?

```cs
namespace App1.App1_XamlTypeInfo
{
    internal partial class XamlTypeInfoProvider
    {
        private void InitTypeTables()
        {
            _typeNameTable = new string[444];
            _typeNameTable[0] = "Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary";
            _typeNameTable[1] = "Object";
            _typeNameTable[2] = "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources";
            //...

            _typeTable = new global::System.Type[444];
            _typeTable[0] = typeof(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary);
            _typeTable[1] = typeof(global::System.Object);
            _typeTable[2] = typeof(global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.XamlControlsResources);
            //...
        }

        private int LookupTypeIndexByName(string typeName)
        {
            if (_typeNameTable == null)
            {
                InitTypeTables();
            }
            for (int i=0; i<_typeNameTable.Length; i++)
            {
                if(0 == string.CompareOrdinal(_typeNameTable[i], typeName))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        //There's an implementation here, but this is just to illustrate it exists
        private List<IXamlMetadataProvider> OtherProviders { get; }
        private IXamlType CheckOtherMetadataProvidersForName(string typeName) { /*...*/ }
    }
}
```

---

#### EDIT

1. The generated classes don't have the necessary `partial` modifiers to modify the generated class.
2. Adding an explicit implementation to `App` causes the entire `XamlTypeInfo.g.cs` creation to fail.
3. From the build log, it looks like XamlTypeInfo.g.cs is generated by the target `MarkupCompilePass1`. I'm considering my own build task to run Roslyn to modify the class, although it would be nice if that could handle `OtherProviders` as well.

Comment: Hi, we do not recommend that you directly modify the content in the `XamlTypeInfoProvider`. Can you explain your application scenario, and the compilation time of the project is significantly higher than expected?

Comment: I wouldn't call compilation time longer than expected, although performance improvement is always nice. My complaint is with the app launch time, with the generated code looping over a large array when a dictionary would be a better choice. (That said, I'm also not certain that the .NET Native toolchain would play well here)


I may be making a bigger deal about this than necessary. Profiling has been semi-inconsistent in showing the impact relative to my code. The array just strikes me as not scaling well in a large app, especially since referenced dependencies would also use an array.

Comment: Hi, The class is that Visual Studio automatically generates during the application writing process. We do not recommend modifying it. It might be possible to do that, and you can try it, if there are any new discoveries, welcome to share it.